# Enable Internal app sharing in fully managed device controlled through android management api

Tags: android, google-play, android-management-api

I want to enable Internal app sharing in fully managed device so that I can send a link with update to specific users in an enterprise.

I tried tapping 7 times on play store version in playstore settings but every time I get a message "Google Play Store is up to date".

How I can activate internal app sharing on a managed device so that I can share app url for testing an application update ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internal app sharing is currently disabled on managed devices. The reason for that is that it allows to install a non-prod version of an app, which is something the administrator needs to be able to control.

We are considering exposing a policy field to enable internal app sharing, but we cannot share any timeline at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: Is there an update on this? We use Work profile for our Org and not been able to use Internal App Sharing :(